# Why does every font-color change on my website when i change the font-color on one of my menu titles?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, animation, wordpress-theming

Whenever i add the random color class on one of the Menu title's, it changes the font-color on the whole website body

This is the HTML on the Menu on the wordpress website

```css
  strong {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours {
  0% {
    color: #39f;
  }
  15% {
    color: #8bc5d1;
  }
  30% {
    color: #f8cb4a;
  }
  45% {
    color: #95b850;
  }
  60% {
    color: #944893;
  }
  75% {
    color: #c71f00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bdb280;
  }
  100% {
    color: #39f;
  }
}

#scroll-container {
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-text {
  /* animation properties */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  /*more*/
}


/* for Firefox */

@-moz-keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}


/* for Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="scroll-text"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i><strong style=""> FLASH SALE GET UP TO 25% OFF EVERYTHING APPLY CODE "HTYCNQX2" AT CHECKOUT<strong><div> </div></div></div>
```

This is the picture of what its doing when i add the CSS/HTML

[Picture of font-color on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHEcO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit was a malformed `<strong>` closing tag in this line:

```
<strong style=""> FLASH SALE GET UP TO 25% OFF EVERYTHING APPLY CODE "HTYCNQX2" AT CHECKOUT<strong>
```

It should be

```
<strong style=""> FLASH SALE GET UP TO 25% OFF EVERYTHING APPLY CODE "HTYCNQX2" AT CHECKOUT</strong>
```

Notice the difference in the ` closing tag.

When there are malformed HTML tags, the user agent will attempt to render the site anyway in most cases. In this case since a closing `<strong>` tag was replaced with an opening `<strong>` tag. The user-agent did it's best to figure out what was right by making everything after that, now stranded, opening `<strong>` tag 'strong'.

```css
  strong {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours {
  0% {
    color: #39f;
  }
  15% {
    color: #8bc5d1;
  }
  30% {
    color: #f8cb4a;
  }
  45% {
    color: #95b850;
  }
  60% {
    color: #944893;
  }
  75% {
    color: #c71f00;
  }
  90% {
    color: #bdb280;
  }
  100% {
    color: #39f;
  }
}

#scroll-container {
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-text {
  /* animation properties */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
  /*more*/
}


/* for Firefox */

@-moz-keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}


/* for Chrome */

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <div id="scroll-container">
    <div id="scroll-text"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i><strong style=""> FLASH SALE GET UP TO 25% OFF EVERYTHING APPLY CODE "HTYCNQX2" AT CHECKOUT</strong><div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong>This will happen to anything wrapped in a &lt;strong&gt; tag because of the css animation being attached to &lt;strong&gt; tag</strong>
  </div>
  <p>I'm a &lt;p&gt; tag in the body but with no strong tag</p>
</body>
```